# How can I remove a ding from the edge of the iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone

I dropped my iPhone 5 and it left a dig on the shiny edge of the phone.  I was wondering what they best way to try to remove the ding would be.

Should I sand paper it with fine grain?  But I'm afraid it'll scratch it up more.

I could sand it with fine sandpaper, and then use a black sharpie to cover it up.  (I have a black iPhone 5.)

Answer (score 2):

You will make it worse, especially if its the black model. Just live with it.